# Python class attribute can't use its own object

Tags: python, class, attributes, nodes, singly-linked-list

I'm new to python and writing two classes to define a singly linkedlist object. I'm having a problem with my _Node class. For the 'next' attribute of the _Node class, I want to set its type to be either a _Node object or None, that's where I wrote Optional[_Node]. But the Pycharm IDE doesn't recognize it. Could someone please help me with this issue? Thanks a lot.

```
from typing import Any, Optional

class _Node:
    """ A node in a linked list.

    Note that this is considered a "private class", one which is only meant
    to be used in this module by the LinkedList class, but not by client 
    code.

    === Attributes ===
    item:
        The data stored in this node.
    next:
        The next node in the List, or None if there are no more nodes.
    """

    item: Any
    next: Optional[_Node]

    def __init__(self, item: Any):
        """ Initialize a new node storing <item>, with no next node.
        """
        self.item = item
        self.next = None # Initailly pointing to nothing
```

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion as this is the first time I post a question on Stact Overflow. I have corrected the format according to your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the following import at the top of your file to enable references to classes that have [not yet been defined](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/#enabling-the-future-behavior-in-python-3-7)

```
from __future__ import annotations
```